# Change "Show X entries" text for page length option

Tags: jquery, datatables

I need to remove the text "show" and "entries" from a DataTable plugin via jQuery.  I am using the CDN so I can not edit the raw code.

```
<div class="dataTables_length" id="example_length">
    <label>
       Show
          <select name="example_length" aria-controls="example" class="">
       entries
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Not a Duplicate. your reference did not answer the question.  Those solutions removed the div.  Need to replace the text.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`language.lengthMenu`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language.lengthMenu) option.

For example:

```
$('#example').DataTable({
   "language": {
      "lengthMenu": "_MENU_"
   }
});
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.  Was even able to change the "search". DataTables is great.